# XBRL Format XML Root Node Attributes Python

Tags: python, elementtree

I want get all the attributes of a root node from this link: 
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/75829/000144530512003029/pll-20120731.xml

```
Main_Page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/75829/000144530512003029/pll-20120731.xml")
                tree = ET.parse(Main_Page)
                root = tree.getroot()
List=root.attrib
```

But List has shown me 0 Length Array. So how can i get the Attribute Values. And it do not have any attrribute key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ElementTree: Working with Namespaces and Qualified Names](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm)

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

Main_Page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/75829/000144530512003029/pll-20120731.xml")
for event, (name, value) in ET.iterparse(Main_Page, ['start-ns']):
    print name, ':', value
```

prints

```
country : http://xbrl.sec.gov/country/2011-01-31
dei : http://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2011-01-31
iso4217 : http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217
link : http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase
pll : http://www.pall.com/20120731
us-gaap : http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2011-01-31
utreg : http://www.xbrl.org/2009/utr
xbrldi : http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi
xbrli : http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance
xlink : http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
```

Comment: But it gives me an Exception:

Comment: @ZaidIqbal, What exception? Could you paste traceback?

Comment: for event,(name, value) in ET1.iterparse(Main_Page, ['start-ns']):ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: @ZaidIqbal, Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: i am using version Python 2.7

Comment: @ZaidIqbal, Sorry, but it works for me in Window 7 (Python 2.7.5), Ubuntu 13.04 (Python 2.7.4).. Did you copy&paste my code?

Comment: Have you get the problem?

Comment: @ZaidIqbal, I don't know what `get the problem` means.

Comment: Nothing i am using these 2 lines in between the loop and urlib2.open():tree = ET.parse(Main_Page)
                root = tree.getroot()